# Using aws-sdk-php in Laravel Class Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to use package aws-sdk-php in my Laravel App.
According to [documentation](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php) it should work as i have included file as following:

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

class MyController extends Controller
{
   //My Function Code
}
```

and class's directory is:

> vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\s3\S3Client.php

and namespace used in class `S3Client` is:

```
namespace Aws\S3
```

But its giving me error:

> class S3Client not found

What am i missing here?

I am using laravel 5.0.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code where you're using it? Without that code we can only guess as to what the problem is.

Comment: I have mentioned, i am using it in MyController.

Comment: I think, would be better if you post your composer.json file. In my case, sometimes, laravel, presents the same weird behavior. The problem is in the autoload declarations... try running `composer install`

Comment: Then please post your controller code, or we can't really help

Comment: @Jonathon I have mentioned. Please check now. Thanks

Comment: Can you include more where you're actually using the class? That error doesn't appear if you simply `use` a class that cannot be found. It would also be helpful if you post your `composer.json` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel package in your composer.json file? as mentioned in this [link](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel). I don't have high reputation to comment.